# jest everything after expect isn't called

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, babel-jest

my jest is not working as I expect it. See:

```
const res = {
        send: (content) => {

            expect(content).toEqual({
                app_status: 501,
                errors: {
                    jwt: {
                        location: 'body',
                        param: 'jwt',
                        value: undefined,
                        msg: 'The jwt is required'
                    }
                }
            });

            console.log("after expect");

            done();

        },
};
```

Basically EVERYTHING after the `expect(content).toEqual ...` in `res.send` is not called. I find that very confusing. I am getting no error except for that my test's are taking too long (because `done`) is not called and the test is not "closed". So my question is, am I missing something obviously?

Comment: Are you sure `res.send` is called? I don't see any code doing so. You could try to debug your code with some `console.log` statements and see if they show up or just using a `debugger` statement and see what happens when it breaks there: https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Comment: Yes, it is called. I already tested it by logging the content before and after the expect. It seem's like expect is freezing or blocking furterer execution.

Comment: What if you change expect to: `expect(true).toEqual(true)` and then deliberately fail with `expect(true).toEqual(false)`?

Comment: ok if have made a `expect(true).toBeTruthy()` it passes on. So i guess an "failed" `expect` stops further execution which is why `done()` is never called. It's just sad that the error isn't displayed it only show's `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` which is useless without the failed `expect`

Comment: I don't think a failed test should prevent the done to be called, try `expect(false).toBeTruthy()` and see if that causes `done` not to be called. Maybe your expect throws an exception that's silently caught or content has a circular reference. You could try to log content: `console.log("content:",JSON.stringify(content,undefined,2))` make sure you json stringify objects when logging, when the object is mutated the mutation shows in the console and you're looking at the object as it is now, not as it was when you logged it.\

Comment: So I tried `expect(false).toBeTruthy();` followed by `done();` and done is never called.

Comment: To be honest it makes sense to me that "done" is never called. If the first expect fails you have to fix it because you would probably have follow up errors in the expectations, so you need to fix it anyway. It's just super annoying since you have to debug which expect fails. There has to be a way to display the failed expect.

Comment: I don't have that in jasmine, maybe it's because you have your `expect` in a mock? Async tests fail immediately and on why it failed instead of timing out.

Comment: Hmh, but the mock is just an object with a function that is passed as an dependency to the service i want to test.

Comment: @HMR are your using babel as well? Because i just wrapped the `expect(true).toBe(false)` in an try catch and it seems like jest throws errors (so you are right about the "expect throws an exception that's silently").

Answer (score 0):

See [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks):

> If the `expect` statement fails, it throws an error and `done()` is not called. If we want to see in the test log why it failed, we have to wrap `expect` in a `try` block and pass the error in the `catch` block to `done`. Otherwise, we end up with an opaque timeout error that doesn't show what value was received by `expect(data)`.

Thus, we can modify your code as follows:

```js
const res = {
        send: (content) => {

            try {
                expect(content).toEqual({
                    app_status: 501,
                    errors: {
                        jwt: {
                            location: 'body',
                            param: 'jwt',
                            value: undefined,
                            msg: 'The jwt is required'
                        }
                    }
                });

                console.log("after expect");

                done();
            } catch (error) {
                done(error);
            }

        },
};
```

As long as `res.send` gets called, the test will complete with either the `expect` error or with a pass.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work fine. I added asynchronous since `send` may be called asynchronously:

```
const createResponse = () => {
  var resolve;
  const p = new Promise(
    (r,reject)=>resolve=r
  );
  return [
    {
      send: (value) => {
        resolve(value)
      }
    },
    p
  ];
};

test('(async) fail', done => {
  //Router
  const router = express.Router();
  //Endpoint to fetch version
  router.get('/api/version', (req, res) => {
    setTimeout(x=>res.send('v1'),10)
  });
  const request = {
    method: 'GET'
  };
  let [response,p] = createResponse()
  router.stack[0].handle(request, response, () => {});
  p.then(
    x=>expect(x).toBe('v2'),
    reject=>expect("should not reject").toBe(reject)
  ).then(
    x=>done()
    //,x=>done() //this will cause all tests to pass
  );
});
```

To answer your question in the comment; consider the following code:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
//Endpoint to fetch version
router.get('/api/version', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});
const request = {
  method: 'GET'
};
const response = {
  send: (value) => {
    debugger;//pause here and see the stack
    throw new Error("Hello Error.");
  }
};
router.stack[0].handle(
  request,
  response, 
  //this is the function done in route.js:
  // https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js#L127
  err => {
    console.error(err.message);//console errors Hello Error.
  }
);
```

Send throws an error but send is called by your mock which is called by express [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L95-L97). So express catches the exception and then ends up [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js#L127) (`done` is not from just but your callback).

So it'll call your callback with an error, skipping `done` from jist and not throwing anything (maybe showing something in log). Since your callback doesn't do anything it times out.

You could try to call `done` from jist in the callback (at `console.error(err.message);`).

**[UPDATE]**

Careful trying to catch the error thrown by `expect` the following will tell me 1 test passed:

```
test('(async) fail', done => {
  try{
    expect(true).toBe(false);
  }catch(e){

  }
  done();
});
```

Comment: i build you an example: https://gitlab.com/pesdfa/jest-express. Just clone it. run npm run test and you will get the timeout.

Comment: I also came up with promises, but I would like to know the problem with the expect in the express router. It seems like the express router somehow changes the behavior of jest in some way.

Comment: I wrote my own expect function that takes the jest expect and done. Executes the expect in a try catch and then fail the test if there is an error catched. Tho i don't like that solution it works

Comment: @pesdfa I updated the answer, express is silently catching the error that jist throws. I think it's best to keep your expects in the `test` method not in the mocks.

Comment: @pesdfa Made one more update at the end, it seems jist `expect` needs to throw in test to fail (see update) an obviously failed test will show up as passed. It sucks when you have to unit test your unit test framework.